# Create multinested JSON from URL in Javascript for d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have the following issue. I have a flat json available from a URL which I want to load with Javascript as nested JSON in a d3.js chart. My code is as follows:

```
d3.json('http://88.99.13.199:3000/measures', function(err, mydata) { 
   mydata.forEach(function(val) { 
      var measuresdata=[];
      var ent = [];
      var plir = [];
      var subm = [];
      ent.push({
          name: "entaxeis",
          size: val.entaxeis
      });
      plir.push({
          name: "pliromes",
          size: val.pliromes
      });
      subm.push({
          name: val.submeasure_code,
          children:{ent, plir}
      });
      measuresdata.push({
          name: val.measure_code,
          children:{subm}
      });
      console.log(measuresdata);
   });
   console.log(measuresdata);
});
```

I want my json to be as follows:

```
{
   "name": "Μ01",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "1.1",
     "children": [
      {"name": "entaxeis", "size": 456123},
      {"name": "pliromes", "size": 3812}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "M03",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "3.1",
     "children": [
      {"name": "entaxeis", "size": 456123},
      {"name": "pliromes", "size": 3812}
     ]
    },
   ]
 }
(..)
```

and so on. It's kind of a puzzle so any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have added the `d3.js` tag, I think the easiest solution is to use the [d3.nest()](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests) function to group by key, and then use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the resulting array to create the required structure:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.measure_code; })
  .entries(mydata)
  .map(function(measure) {
    return {
      name: measure.key,
      children: measure.values.map(function(submeasure) {
        return {
          name: submeasure.submeasure_code,
          children: [
            { name: "entaxeis", size: submeasure.entaxeis },
            { name: "pliromes", size: submeasure.pliromes }
          ]
        };
      })
    };
  });
```

Comment: I love your answer, however I have one issue. Your suggestion creates succesfully my JSON in the desired format, but it creates a record for eac measure_code although some are with the same name. I want it to put all submeasures under the same measure.

Comment: I've updated the answer to group the measures by `measure_code` by using d3.nest.